# Why the determinant of the stress energy tensor of dust matter fields $\det T^{\mu\nu}=0$?

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider the stress energy tensor of dust matter fields
\begin{equation}
M=\begin{pmatrix}
c^2&cv_x&cv_y&cv_z\\
cv_x&v_xv_x&v_xv_y&v_xv_z\\
cv_y&v_yv_x&v_yv_y&v_yv_z\\
cv_z&v_zv_x&v_zv_y&v_zv_z
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The determinant of the matrix
\begin{equation}
\det M=0.
\end{equation}

Consider the specialty of the stress energy tensor and the fact that determinant in the higher dimension usually represent the volume, I found it to be somewhat interesting.

Why the determinant of the  stress energy tensor of the matter fields $\det T^{\mu\nu}=0$? Does it generalize?

Comment: That's not a stress-energy tensor. For incoherent dust, stress-energy tensor is $T^{\mu\nu} = \rho_0 u^\mu u^\nu$, where $\rho_0$ is density in the rest frame of the dust and $u$ is dust velocity four-vector $u = (\gamma c, \gamma \mathbf v)$. I.e. your matrix is missing density and the gamma factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the matrix you've written down, the rows are all proportional to each other.  For example, the second row is $v_x/c$ times the first row, and so forth.  This means that the determinant of this matrix will automatically vanish.

More generally, one can also always find a local orthonormal reference frame in which the stress-energy tensor is diagonal (i.e., its off-diagonal components are all zero.)  In this reference frame, the determinant of the stress-energy tensor would just be the product of the energy density $\rho$ with the three pressures $P_x$, $P_y$, and $P_z$.  Any situation in which the determinant vanishes is one in which at least one of these quantities is zero, but you can't necessarily say much more than that.  And there are plenty of types of matter for which this product is non-zero — radiation, for example, or dust moving with some kind of Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of velocities.